# Can gmaps4rails return an image-like map?

Tags: javascript, css, ruby-on-rails, coffeescript, gmaps4rails

I currently am using gmaps4ails and have an interactive map returned. Is there a way to get a more static like image instead?

I've tried modifying the following code but for some reason on the phone pinch and zoom doesn't work

```
if MODETECT.device.phone
      @map_options =
        disableDefaultUI:       true #false has the street view capability
        disableDoubleClickZoom: false
        type:                   "ROADMAP" # HYBRID, ROADMAP, SATELLITE, TERRAIN
        draggable:              false # don't allow to drag map
        scrollwheel:            true
        zoomControl:            true

    else
      @map_options =
        disableDefaultUI:       true #false has the street view capability
        disableDoubleClickZoom: false
        type:                   "ROADMAP" # HYBRID, ROADMAP, SATELLITE, TERRAIN
        draggable:              true # don't allow to drag map
        scrollwheel:            false #can't use the scroll whell to zoom
        zoomControl:            true #widget that allows control zoom without pinch
```

...

```
createMap : ->
    defaultOptions =
      maxZoom:                @map_options.maxZoom
      minZoom:                @map_options.minZoom
      zoom:                   @map_options.zoom
      center:                 @createLatLng(@map_options.center_latitude, @map_options.center_longitude)
      mapTypeId:              google.maps.MapTypeId[@map_options.type]
      mapTypeControl:         @map_options.mapTypeControl
      disableDefaultUI:       @map_options.disableDefaultUI
      disableDoubleClickZoom: @map_options.disableDoubleClickZoom
      draggable:              @map_options.draggable
      scrollwheel:            @map_options.scrollwheel
      zoomControl:            @map_options.zoomControl
```

It seems to work in the sense for draggable, but scrollwheel and zoomControl on the phone isn't working.

Comment: Didn't need this option so it's not built in the gem. Consider contributing :)

Comment: Yeah this might be interesting because when the map is in the middle of the page and you scroll, then you zoom out when you hit the middle of the page. Also on the phone it moves the map when you scroll with your finger.